# error when exiting tkinter window update and update_idletasks

Tags: python, tkinter

I have a problem with functions update() and update_idletasks() in tkinter
they work fine except that when closing the window, either by cliking the "Exit"
button or  the "x" to close the window in Windows, the following error lines show up:

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "D:\Python\VisualStudio\test4\test4\test4.py", line 14, in 
label.configure(text = str(i)) # i is actually updated by an asynchronous function, like a wifi stream File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py", line 1675, in configure return self.*configure('configure', cnf, kw) File "C:\Users\Owner\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter_*init**.py", line 1665, in _configure self.tk.call(_flatten((self._w, cmd)) + elf._options(cnf))
_tkinter.TclError: invalid command name ".!label"
Press any key to continue . . .

Ultimately I want Tkinter to show the incoming characters from a wi-fi, which is why I cannot use mainloop.

Comment: import tkinter as tk

def increment(j): # this simulates my asynchronous function
 return j+1

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root,text="Name")
label.pack()

exit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=root.destroy)
exit_button.pack()
i=0
while True:
 label.configure(text = str(i)) # i is actually updated by an asynchronous function, like a wifi stream
 i = increment(i)               # these two lines are jut to simulate that
 root.update_idletasks()
 root.update()

Comment: Please refer to this guide on how to provide a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example), and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Remember, we can't help you if we don't know what you've already tried.

Comment: Please don't put code in the comment section. You can [edit] your question to add requested information.

Comment: The error is telling you that you're trying to configure a widget that has been deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I want to display the characters coming asynchronously from a wifi on a Tkinter window
After several problems I was able to come to the following solution.
Many thanks to JRiggles and Bryan Oakles

This is my source code:

```
import tkinter as tk

def my_async(): # this simulates my asynchronous function, i will come from wifi
    global i
    i = i+1

i = 0
window_is_alive = True

root = tk.Tk()
label = tk.Label(root,text="Name")
label.pack()

def destroy_window():
    global window_is_alive
    window_is_alive = False

#Reassign the Close Window Control Icon
root.protocol("WM_DELETE_WINDOW", destroy_window)

exit_button = tk.Button(root, text="Exit", command=destroy_window)
exit_button.pack()

while True:
    label.configure(text = str(i)) # i is actually updated by an asynchronous function, like a wifi stream
    my_async()                     # these two lines are just to simulate that
    root.update_idletasks()
    root.update()
    if window_is_alive == False:
        root.destroy()
        break
```